# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' - Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have been through the various Stack Overflow questions and non of the answers resolve the issue for me.
It is likely a path 'thing' that I am not seeing.

Have installed `pandas`, it says its there, but `numpy` will import and `pandas` won't.

Any ideas? What am I missing?

If I enter:

```
!pip3 install pandas
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\ron mcmillan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (1.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\ron mcmillan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\ron mcmillan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\ron mcmillan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\ron mcmillan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.14.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm going to give a completely new, opinionated, answer.

It looks like you've got at least two installations of Python, one in `..python\python38`, and one in `..\python\python38-32`. `pandas` is installed on the first, but `jupyter` is running on the second. You've got a version of `pip` for each, plus a third one in `Microsoft\WindowsApps`.

[This happens](https://xkcd.com/1987/).

On Windows, you are probably safe to just uninstall all the versions of Python on your computer.  Then download [Miniconda for Windows](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). Miniconda is, like `pip`, a package manager for Python; but unlike pip, is able to also install non-Python files, which makes all sorts of things much easier. It's called 'Miniconda' to distinguish it from 'Anaconda', which is `conda` plus almost all the packages a data scientist might need -- Miniconda just gives you the package manager `conda`, and you can then choose to install what you actually want.

Once `conda` is installed, create a new conda environment (`conda create -n MYNEWENV` -- if you have twenty minutes then [read the quickstart explanation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html)) and then try to download everything with `conda install...`

You can specify which 'channel' you download packages from, but you probably don't need to. Just try `conda install jupyter numpy pandas`; or search [the Conda cloud](https://anaconda.org/) for the specifics of whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the python installation which is running jupyter is the one that has pandas. Run `where jupyter` (`which` on linux/mac), and make sure it matches the paths above. Also try `where pip` to make sure the installations of `pip`, `python`, and `jupyter` match.

To be sure you're using a specific version of python+pip to install a package, you can call pip the module rather than the script, e.g. with `c:\users\ron mcmillan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python -m pip install [pkg]`

I'd consider using an environment manager such as [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) to simplify environments & installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas
```

There is a lengthy explanation [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/).

Answer (score 0):

Going through the lengthy explanation above - will need to go through it again.

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
```

returns:

```
'c:\users\ron' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

import sys
sys.path
```

returns:

```
['C:\\Users\\Ron McMillan',
 'c:\\users\\ron mcmillan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38- 
  32\\python38.zip',
 'c:\\users\\ron mcmillan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\ron mcmillan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\ron mcmillan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32',
 '',
 'c:\\users\\ron mcmillan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'c:\\users\\ron mcmillan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'c:\\users\\ron mcmillan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\ron mcmillan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
 'c:\\users\\ron mcmillan\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions',
 'C:\\Users\\Ron McMillan\\.ipython']
```

!type python

returns

The system cannot find the file specified.

And in the Command Prompt:

where jupyter

```
C:\users\ron mcmillan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Scripts\jupyter.exe
```

and

```
where pip

C:\users\ron mcmillan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\users\ron mcmillan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\users\ron mcmillan\appdata\local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\pip.exe
```

So, Jupyter note finding Python?

Comment: It looks like you've got two installations of Python, one in `..python\python38`, and one in `..\python\python38-32`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank you.

Yes, I knew it was messy - to the point I din't get it. The picture makes sense.